# format json files to pretty reading

Tags: python, json, data-science

I got a json file whose structure looks like this:

```
{
   "data": {
     "msg": "success",
     "data": {
        "levelConfigList": "name,id\n1,10001\n2,10002\n3,10004\n4,10003\n5,10005",
        "profitConfigList": "id,num,list\n1,1.042,\"[16,17,19,20,21,23,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,40]\"\n2,1.042,\"[17,18,20,21,22,24,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,41]\""
   }
}
```

I can make it more readable by convert to .yaml format, yet a .json file looks like below is preferred:

```
{
 "data": {
    "msg": "success",
    "data": {
        "levelConfigList": [
            {
                "name": 1,
                "id": 10001
            },
            {
                "name": 2,
                "id": 10002
            }
        ]
   }
 }     
}
```

I manually use python to make it in an unly way:

```
import json
from csv import reader

with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  jsd = f.read()
jsd = json.loads(jsd)

# split json value to list
jsline = jsd['data']['data'][key].splitlines()
list_dict = list(reader(jsline))

# map the first item in list as key and the rest each as value, and combine together
newdict = []
for i in list_dict[1:]:
     newdict.append((dict(zip(list_dict[0], i))))
jsd['data']['data'][key] = newdict
```

Lastly, using `for key in jsd['data']['data']:` to iterate all the keys and replace them I finally get the result. Is there a nicer way to get this done?

And besides, a deficiency of this method is that all my value are strings:

```
     ...
     "profitConfigList": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "num": "1.042",
                "list": "[16,17,19,20,21,23,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,40]"
            }
     ...
```

yet I want to keep the type of the value as they originally were, is there any method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a nested array notation is each row in the lists potentially also a json object?

In that case you can do something like this:

```py
def parse_nested_list(x):
  lines = x.splitlines()
  lines = list(csv.DictReader(lines))
  return [{k: json.loads(v) for k, v in line.items()} for line in lines

jsd['data']['data']['profitConfigList'] = parse_nested_list(jsd['data']['data']['profitConfigList'])
jsd['data']['data']['levelConfigList'] = parse_nested_list(jsd['data']['data']['levelConfigList'])
```

Comment: It works well except the `key : values` like `"ConfigList": "name,color\nあ,#A7A39B,\nい,#D5FEAD\nう,#98EBFB\nえ,#B067E3\nお,#FBE68D"` which contains special characters where `json.loads()` raises error. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Solved this by rewriting return to `try: jslist.append({k: json.loads(v)}) except:jslist.append({k, v)}, return jslist ` where previously `jslist = []` added to function.